# How to intercept SOAP message and transforming it before processing?

Tags: java, web-services, xslt, soap, transform

I have task where I need to transform custom SOAP message. At the beginning I have to get this custom SOAP message, then I need to transform this message using XSLT, then process this message in my WebService. The reverse process is repeated.

I have XSLT file and method for transforming SOAP message, but I don't know where I need to call this method for transforming. How do I intercept SOAP message and where I have to do it? Because I have only class with one method (example below) and i don't understand how I can transform this message before processing in webservice.

```
@WebService
public class Calculator {

public String showCard(final CreditCard creditCard) {
    return creditCard.toString();
}
```

}

Here is the [technical mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KQqz.gif) what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I intercept SOAP message and where I have to do it?

You need a SoapHandler to capture the soap request before the execution of the bussiness logic of the endpoint, and other SoapHandler to transform the outbound response.

Define a SoapHandler class (example extracted from [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/))

```
public class CalculatorSoapHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{

   @Override
   public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

    Boolean isRequest = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    //for response message only, true for outbound messages, false for inbound
    if(!isRequest){

    try{
        SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnv = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnv.getHeader();

        //process....

        }catch(SOAPException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }

      //continue other handler chain
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    }


}
```

Create a soap handler XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<javaee:handler-chains 
     xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <javaee:handler-chain>
    <javaee:handler>
      <javaee:handler-class>com.CalculatorSoapHandler</javaee:handler-class>
    </javaee:handler>
  </javaee:handler-chain>
</javaee:handler-chains>
```

Attach SOAP Handler to Web Service using @HandlerChain

```
@WebService
@HandlerChain(file="handler-chain.xml")
public class Calculator {
```

If you use a jax-ws framework like CXF or spring-WS, check the documentation to see specific configuration